# My Python script is not formatting the CSV file properly if there are NULL values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have the following Python 3 code that runs a database stored procedure and puts the data into a dataframe and then saves it to a `.csv` file.

It works, but if there is a `null value` at the end, it just leaves a trailing comma.

Here is my script:

```
def GenerateCSV(fileName):

    connection_string = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=dev;DATABASE=Cities;UID=z;PWD=z"
    connection_url = URL.create(
        "mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})

    engine = sa.create_engine(connection_url)

    qry = text("EXECUTE dbo.sp_city_parser")
    with engine.connect() as con:
        rs = con.execute(qry)

    df = pd.read_sql_query(qry, engine)

    df.to_csv(fileName, encoding='utf-8', mode='a', index= False, header=False)
```

The program generates a `csv` file that looks like this:

```
*CityName,*CityID,*CityCountryCode,*CitySize,CityPopulation
Tokyo,656,5,X-Large,
Chicago,887,9,Large,
Berlin,432,3,Large,
```

As you can see, since `CityPopulation` is NULL, it just leaves a trailing comma with nothing there.

Shouldn't it leave something like this? Where the `''` represents the null value?

```
Tokyo,656,5,X-Large,''
```

Thanks!

Comment: The trailing comma is correct. You have 5 columns, so you should have 4 commas (there is always one less comma than there are columns). `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` or `Name, ID, Code, Size, Population`

Comment: If, in your post, you meant `Tokyo,656,5,X-Large,''` instead of `Tokyo,656,5,X-Large,,,` then no, the csv file would not store the `NULL` value as `''`, the trailing comma is how it represents another column. If you changed the order of the columns to `Name, ID, Code, Population, Size` then an example value would be `Tokyo,656,5,,X-Large` . [CSVs represent null data with two successive delimiters, eg a comma in this case](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-unload-considerations#:~:text=Empty%20Strings%20and,contains%20zero%20characters.)

Comment: Yes, I did mean that..sorry and thanks for noticing! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to represent null values in csv file with something else you can pass `na_rep` param to your method :

```
df.to_csv(fileName, na_rep ='NULL', ... )
```

output :

```
Tokyo,656,5,X-Large,NULL
Chicago,887,9,Large,NULL
Berlin,432,3,Large,NULL
```

or you can quote your values :

```
df.to_csv(fileName, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, ...)
```

output:

```
"Tokyo",656,5,"X-Large",""
"Chicago",887,9,"Large",""
"Berlin",432,3,"Large",""
```

and to be clear here , none of these is necessary to declare null values in csv file. Any csv reader would understand that column is null.